# Set \bottomrule of two uneven tables to same height

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs, makecell, vspace

I have two parallel tables not equal in height. I'd like to set `\bottomrule` of the shorter left table to the same height as the right one.
Is this even possible without rearranging the rows? Using `\vspace{}` is one approach I tried, but it's too tricky. So I asked myself if there is a better solution?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e, tabularx, makecell, booktabs}

\newcommand\mc[1]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{%
    >{\RaggedRight}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]\centering\small\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \caption{Two uneven parallel tables.\label{tab:test}}
    \begin{tabularx}{.45\columnwidth}[t]{XX}
        \toprule
            \mc{Column1} & \mc{Column2} \\
        \midrule
            Row 1 & Row 1 \\
            Row 2 & Row 2 \\
            Row 3 & Row 3 \\
            Row 4 & Row 4 \\% \vspace{3.05pt} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tabularx}{.45\columnwidth}[t]{XX}
        \toprule
           \mc{Column1} & \mc{Column2} \\
        \midrule
            Row 1 & \makecell[l]{Row 1 with \\ line break} \\
            Row 2 & Row 2 \\
            \makecell[l]{Row 2 with \\ line break} & Row 2 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome (2) wjy make it as two tables, and not just one, and then use a black column between the two parts and use `\cmidrule` for the lines?

Comment: This is just a snippet. It's a bigger table with text above and underneath. I divided it so it doesn't take too much vertical space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `\hbox` the two tables up and then display them in two tables which add the contents of the other table as a `\vphantom` and below that a `\bottomrule`. Note that you should not use `\bottomrule` in both tables, it's added automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e, tabularx, makecell, booktabs}

\newcommand\mc[1]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{%
    >{\RaggedRight}m{#1}}

\newsavebox\resizeboxA
\newsavebox\resizeboxB
\newcommand\BottomRuleAligned
  {%
    \begingroup
    \def\additionalspace{\noalign{\vfill}}%
    \setbox\resizeboxA\hbox\bgroup
      \ignorespaces
  }
\newcommand\EndFirstTable
  {%
      \ifhmode\unskip\fi
    \egroup
    \setbox\resizeboxB\hbox\bgroup
      \ignorespaces
  }
\newcommand\EndSecondTable
  {%
      \ifhmode\unskip\fi
    \egroup
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      \vphantom{\usebox\resizeboxB}\usebox\resizeboxA\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \BottomRuleAlignedTableSep
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      \vphantom{\usebox\resizeboxA}\usebox\resizeboxB\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand\BottomRuleAlignedTableSep{\hskip1em}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]\centering\small\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \caption{Two uneven parallel tables.\label{tab:test}}
    \BottomRuleAligned
      \begin{tabularx}{.45\columnwidth}[t]{XX}
          \toprule
              \mc{Column1} & \mc{Column2} \\
          \midrule
              Row 1 & Row 1 \\
              Row 2 & Row 2 \\
              Row 3 & Row 3 \\
              Row 4 & Row 4 \\% \vspace{3.05pt} \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \EndFirstTable
      \begin{tabularx}{.45\columnwidth}[t]{XX}
          \toprule
             \mc{Column1} & \mc{Column2} \\
          \midrule
              Row 1 & \makecell[l]{Row 1 with \\ line break} \\
              Row 2 & Row 2 \\
              \makecell[l]{Row 2 with \\ line break} & Row 2 \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \EndSecondTable
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Same vertical above the table as a single `\begin{tabularx}` has and horizontal spacing reduced to just a space. Now you shouldn't use `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` as both are added automatically (this fixes your spacing difference):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e, tabularx, makecell, booktabs}

\newcommand\mc[1]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{%
    >{\RaggedRight}m{#1}}

\newsavebox\resizeboxA
\newsavebox\resizeboxB
\newcommand\BottomRuleAligned
  {%
    \begingroup
    \def\additionalspace{\noalign{\vfill}}%
    \setbox\resizeboxA\hbox\bgroup
      \ignorespaces
  }
\newcommand\EndFirstTable
  {%
      \ifhmode\unskip\fi
    \egroup
    \setbox\resizeboxB\hbox\bgroup
      \ignorespaces
  }
\newcommand\EndSecondTable
  {%
      \ifhmode\unskip\fi
    \egroup
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      \toprule
      \vphantom{\usebox\resizeboxB}\usebox\resizeboxA\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \BottomRuleAlignedTableSep
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      \toprule
      \vphantom{\usebox\resizeboxA}\usebox\resizeboxB\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand\BottomRuleAlignedTableSep{\space}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]\centering\small\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \caption{Two uneven parallel tables.\label{tab:test}}
    \BottomRuleAligned
      \begin{tabularx}{.45\columnwidth}[t]{XX}
              \mc{Column1} & \mc{Column2} \\
          \midrule
              Row 1 & Row 1 \\
              Row 2 & Row 2 \\
              Row 3 & Row 3 \\
              Row 4 & Row 4 \\% \vspace{3.05pt} \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \EndFirstTable
      \begin{tabularx}{.45\columnwidth}[t]{XX}
             \mc{Column1} & \mc{Column2} \\
          \midrule
              Row 1 & \makecell[l]{Row 1 with \\ line break} \\
              Row 2 & Row 2 \\
              \makecell[l]{Row 2 with \\ line break} & Row 2 \\
      \end{tabularx}
    \EndSecondTable
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks! But there is a bit more space between the caption and the table now, at least in my document. Can't tell exactly why.

Comment: @pCC I fixed the spacing.

Comment: @pCC appreciation is usually expressed in votes (and accepting the most helpful answer -- which you fortunately already did).

Answer (score 4):

Since you load `makecell`, we can have different values of `\arraystretch` for the column heads and the rest of the tables, so here is a solution playing with `\arraystretch`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e, tabularx, makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]\centering\small\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\theadset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.3}}%{\setstretch{0.3}}%
    \caption{Two uneven parallel tables.\label{tab:test}}
   \begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.097}
   \begin{tabularx}{.45\columnwidth}[t]{XX}
\toprule
\thead{Column 1} & \thead{Column 2} \\[-1pt]
\midrule
            Row 1 & Row 1 \\
            Row 2 & Row 2 \\
            Row 3 & Row 3 \\
            Row 4 & Row 4 \\% \vspace{3.05pt} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx} \endgroup
    \begin{tabularx}{.45\columnwidth}[t]{XX}
\toprule
\thead{Column 1} & \thead{Column 2} \\
\midrule
            Row 1 & \makecell[l]{Row 1 with \\ line break} \\
            Row 2 & Row 2 \\
            \makecell[l]{Row 2 with \\ line break} & Row 2 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]